# prove that between any two consecutive roots of $\phi(x)=0$, there lies a root of $\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$

Tags: roots, maxima-minima

> Let $\phi(x)$ is a polynomial function, with real coefficients. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any two consecutive roots of $\phi(x)=0$, then prove that there lies a root of $\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$ in the interval $(\alpha, \beta)$. (here $\lambda$ is a fixed constant).

My approach:

We need to prove that there exists $x\in(\alpha,\beta), $ such that $\phi'(x)=-\lambda \phi(x)$.

Since $\phi(\alpha)=0$ and $\phi(\beta)=0$ and $\phi(x)$ is a polynomial, hence $\phi(x)$ attains a maxima or a minima in $(\alpha, \beta)$; hence, $\phi'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(\alpha, \beta)$.

I do not know how to proceed further. I have been able to verify the above statement for specific cases, but haven't been able to generalize from there.

Also, I don't think the above statement should be true. for example what if $\beta$ was a repeated root of $\phi$ and $\phi'$. something like this

[image]

unfortunately, I haven't been able to generate a specific polynomial that behaves in this way. so I'm stuck

**edit: based on @Hagen von Eitzen's answer, can we use**

1. $f(x)=\phi(x)\cdot x^{\lambda}$ to prove  $x\cdot\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$
2. $f(x)=\phi(x)\cdot e^{tan^{-1}x}$ to prove  $(1+x^2)\cdot\phi'(x)+\phi(x)=0$
3. $f(x)=\phi(x)\cdot e^{x^2/2}$ to prove  $\phi'(x)+x\cdot\phi(x)=0$

Comment: Consider the function $\phi ' + \lambda \phi$. What is its sign at $\alpha$?  What is its sign at $\beta$?

Comment: the sign of $\phi'+\lambda\phi$ at $\alpha,\beta$, will be the sign of $\phi'$ at $\alpha, \beta$. if $\phi $ is increasing at $\alpha$ then it will be decreasing at $\beta$ and vice versa. hence $\phi'(\alpha)\cdot\phi'(\beta)<0$.

Comment: the sign of $\phi'(\alpha)$ could be + or -, depending on the polynomial $\phi$

Comment: if you downvote, please provide a reason too, so that I can make the necessary improvements to this post. thank you.

Comment: I do not know why you have removed your approach : even though you obtained answers it is still important to know what your approach was, especially if other answers discussed it. Please edit the details back again, thank you.

Comment: nobody commented on my approach. I had problems with my approach, and I had other problems related to this question that I wanted to ask(they are in the edit). To avoid asking too many questions in a single post, I split the post into two, based on the type of answers on this post.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon my approach is in this post----> math.stackexchange.com/q/4177161/415432

Comment: Please don't edit your no context question, only after you can copy info from answerers, into your edit.

Comment: @amWhy , what exactly do you want me to remove? The edit is indeed based on an answer, but it is a further question based on that answer

Comment: The "My approach" section was there when I *first* posted this question, same as it is now, word for word, you can check in the edits history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $$f(x)=\phi(x)e^{\lambda x}$$ and apply Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that since $\phi$ is a polynomial, we can write $\phi(x) = (x-\alpha)^n(x-\beta)^m\tilde\phi(x)$ and consider only $\tilde\phi(x)$. Look at cases, as you mentioned. Notice that $\tilde\phi'(\alpha)$ and $\tilde\phi'(\beta)$ cannot both have the same nonzero sign (why?). Let $g(x) = \tilde\phi'(x) + \lambda\tilde\phi(x)$. Then $g(\alpha) = \tilde\phi'(\alpha)$ and $g(\beta) = \tilde\phi'(\beta)$. But these have opposite signs, so we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem on g. Since $g$ has a $0$ in $(\alpha,\beta)$, so will $g(x)(x-\alpha)^n(x-\beta)^m = \phi'(x) + \lambda\phi(x)$.

Comment: i don't understand, $g(\alpha)+g(\beta)$ does not need to be equal to zero.

Comment: Hopefully you agree that if $g(x)$ is zero, your problem is solved. I'm not suggesting you add them, I'm saying you should apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, which says that if a continuous function has opposite signs at the endpoints of $[\alpha,\beta]$, then it must have a zero in between them.

Comment: what if $\alpha, \beta$ are both repeated roots of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ both. in this case, $g(\alpha)=g(\beta)=0$

Comment: You bring up a valid point. You could do something like $g(x) = \phi'(x) + \lambda\phi(x) = (x-\alpha)^n(x-\beta)^m(\tilde \phi'(x) + \lambda \tilde \phi(x))$, where $n$ and $m$ are the multiplicity of the respective roots. Then $\tilde \phi'(x) + \lambda \tilde \phi(x)$ will not be $0$ at either endpoint, and you can use my above argument. If this has a $0$ in between, then certainly $g$ does as well.

Comment: its true that $ \tilde\phi(x)(x-\alpha)^n(x-\beta)^m=\phi(x)$. but is it true that $\phi'(x) = (x-\alpha)^n(x-\beta)^m\tilde\phi'(x)$ ?

Comment: No, it's not. Sorry about that.