# counterexample for prove that between any two consecutive roots of $\phi(x)=0$, there lies a root of $\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$

Tags: solution-verification, roots, maxima-minima

> Let $\phi(x)$ is a polynomial function, with real coefficients. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any two consecutive roots of $\phi(x)=0$, then prove that there lies a root of $\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$ in the interval $(\alpha, \beta)$. (here $\lambda$ is a fixed constant).

*This is a solution-verification type post. This question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4175777/415432). If you have another answer to this question, kindly post it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4175777/415432)*

**My approach:**

We need to prove that there exists $x\in(\alpha,\beta), $ such that $\phi'(x)=-\lambda \phi(x)$.

Since $\phi(\alpha)=0$ and $\phi(\beta)=0$ and $\phi(x)$ is a polynomial, hence $\phi(x)$ attains a maxima or a minima in $(\alpha, \beta)$; hence, $\phi'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(\alpha, \beta)$.

Now, I don't think the above statement should be true, because for example, what if $\beta$ was a repeated root of $\phi$(even no. of times repeated) and $\phi'$(odd no. of times repeated, obviously). something like this
[image]

unfortunately, I haven't been able to generate a specific polynomial that behaves in this way. so I'm stuck.

**My question-**

could someone comment on why my approach was wrong? more specifically, I laid out a "blueprint" for a counter-example(the blue image above) but wasn't able to find an actual counter-example(because such a counter-example doesn't exist). even after solving this problem, I have not been able to entirely convince myself, why such a counterexample shouldn't exist. so that's my question, why can such a counterexample exist not exist?

Comment: If all you're asking for is a polynomial with a double root somewhere, anything of the form $(x-a)(x-b)^2$ should do.

Comment: $\phi(x)$ should have at least 4 roots so that $\phi'(x)$ has an odd number of repeated roots. And $\phi$ should also *not* satisfy $\phi'(x)+\lambda \phi(x)=0$ , for any $x\in(\alpha,\beta)$ , where  α and β are any two consecutive roots of $ϕ(x)=0$

Comment: Well, I'd argue that $1$ is an odd number, and gives graphs like the ones you have drawn, but, OK, just use $(x-a)(x-b)^4$. I'm not trying to address the part about $\phi'+\lambda\phi$. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry into it.

Comment: Consider the function $\phi'/\phi$. Close to $\alpha$ this goes to $\infty$ in your example (convince yourself of this), close to $\beta$ it goes to $-\infty$ (convince yourself of this). Now this function is continuous so it will attain any real value between the roots.

Comment: @Gerry yes, you are right, it is not necessary for $\phi$ to have at least 4 repeated roots. 2 repeated roots should be fine too.